# R function to identify duplicates between various columns AND rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to identify the the rows in a table where there is a duplication between two sets of columns:

[image: table]

Just in case the image is not showing, here is a little pseudocode of the table:

```
data.frame(ind = 1:4,
           f_name   = c("a", "b", "c", "g"),
           l_name   = c("y", "y", "d", "h"),
           s_f_name = c( NA, "a", "a",  NA),
           s_l_name = c( NA, "y", "y",  NA))
```

For example, I want to show that Row 1 and 2 have a duplication between the first/last name AND the secondary first/last name regardless of the row (record) they are in.

I would look for the output:  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE.

I have been using the `duplicated()` function, and I utilize `duplicated(...)|duplicated(..., fromLast = TRUE)` in order to account for any values that have a duplication regardless of the starting index.

Answer (score 0):

Try using logical flags and then merge with your original data, here the code using some `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(ind=1:4,
                 f_name=c('A','B','C','G'),
                 l_name=c('Y','Y','D','H'),
                 s_f_name=c('','A','A',''),
                 s_l_name=c('','Y','Y',''),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Split data
newdf <- df %>% 
  left_join(
    df %>% select(c(ind,f_name,l_name)) %>%
      bind_rows(df %>% select(c(ind,s_f_name,s_l_name)) %>%
                  rename(f_name=s_f_name,l_name=s_l_name)) %>%
      filter(f_name!='') %>%
      mutate(id=paste(f_name,l_name),
             Flag1=duplicated(id,fromLast = T),
             Flag2=duplicated(id),
             Flag3=ifelse(Flag1 | Flag2,T,F)) %>%
      filter(Flag3) %>%
      select(c(ind,Flag3))
  ) %>% replace(is.na(.),F) %>%
  rename(Dup=Flag3)
```

Output:

```
  ind f_name l_name s_f_name s_l_name   Dup
1   1      A      Y                    TRUE
2   2      B      Y        A        Y  TRUE
3   3      C      D        A        Y  TRUE
4   4      G      H                   FALSE
```